# JPA repository method returning no data even though data is present in H2 db

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
ExchangeValue exchangeValue = repository.findByFromAndTo(from, to);
```

The exchangeValue is coming as null though data is present in  h2 db

[H2 data snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Cd30.png)

My code url is https://github.com/sunny107842/currency-exchange

```
package com.sunny.microservices.currencyexchangeservice;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface ExchangeValueRepository extends 
    JpaRepository<ExchangeValue, Long>{


ExchangeValue findByFromAndTo(String from, String to);
}
```

Edit
Entire code can be found at the github url

Exchange class

`

```
package com.sunny.microservices.currencyexchangeservice;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class ExchangeValue {

@Id
private Long id;

@Column(name = "currency_from")
private String from;

@Column(name = "currency_to")
private String to;

private BigDecimal conversionMultiple;
private int port;

public ExchangeValue() {

}

public ExchangeValue(Long id, String from, String to, BigDecimal conversionMultiple) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.conversionMultiple = conversionMultiple;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getFrom() {
    return from;
}

public String getTo() {
    return to;
}

public BigDecimal getConversionMultiple() {
    return conversionMultiple;
}

public int getPort() {
    return port;
}

public void setPort(int port) {
    this.port = port;
}

}
```

Could anyone help me out please? Data is present in the db

i am making this rest call to get the data

```
http://localhost:8001/currency-exchange/from/usd/to/inr
```

Please let me know if any other data is required.

Comment: show ExchangeValue entity

Comment: Recheck you have data b/w from and to, if there is no matching data it will be null

Comment: Can you show your request which you are making? is it `http://localhost:8001/currency-exchange/from/USD/to/INR`

Comment: @sunny what are the values you are passing as **to** and **from** while calling `repository.findByFromAndTo(from, to);`? add a log /sysout before calling it and let me know the value of both

Comment: Hello @sunny you may accept the answer if it was helpful

Comment: @PatelRomil my reputation is less that 15 so i dont have the rights to accept the answer yet, But both your and  zpavel answers can be choosen as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple. In your data.sql you inserted values with uppercase. Try with `http://localhost:8001/currency-exchange/from/USD/to/INR` or change it in data.sql to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Issue was in the rest call.It was the error of case sensitive

Right call should be

```
http://localhost:8001/currency-exchange/from/USD/to/INR
```

instead of

```
 http://localhost:8001/currency-exchange/from/usd/to/inr
```

Answer (score 0):

It was the case sensitive Issue:
*Change usd to USD, ind to INR*

Call

```
GET:    http://localhost:8001/currency-exchange/from/USD/to/INR
```

Comment: Hello @sunny, I glad it helped https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow